# Can I unpack an `nn.ModuleList` inside `nn.Sequential`?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am parametrizing the number of hidden layers of a simple ANN using `nn.ModuleList`. I am wondering if passing this list into a `nn.Sequential` module as follows would lead to any adverse effects with the execution graph.

`nn.Sequential` is not necessary, however it seems cleaner to me to have the entire architecture explicit in the constructor.

```
class ANN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(
        self,
        in_feats=3,
        in_hidden=5,
        n_hidden_layers=3,

    ):
        super(ANN, self).__init__()

        # ====== dynamically register hidden layers ======
        self.hidden_linears = nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(n_hidden_layers):
            self.hidden_linears.append(nn.Linear(in_hidden, in_hidden))
            self.hidden_linears.append(nn.ReLU())
        
        # ====== sequence of layers ======
        self.layers = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_feats, in_hidden),
            nn.ReLU(),
            *self.hidden_linears,
            nn.Linear(in_hidden, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def forward(self, X):
        return self.layers(X)
```

Also open to suggestions of neater ways to put this together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `nn.Sequential.modules()` to get every single part of the Sequential and then pack them into a list.